# Facebook Sharing Debugger does not scrape my picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i use a picture (regular PNG image) from my server on the Sharing debugger tool, i can see the picture and it works well. 
this is the link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.11sheep.com%2Ftemp%2Fpic.png

But when i put the same picture (i use the same PNG file) on my AWS (rather new server) server, i get error and can not see the picture (response code 404). 
This is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsheep-service.info%2FTheOfficeQuest%2FPics%2Fpic.png

Any ideas why this is happening? should i make some kind of server configuration or enter my url to the facebook app somehow?

Comment: When I copy and paste your image url to browser, it gets 404 error. So you should check your url